# How to upload a record from android phone db(sqlite) to a web page

Tags: android

### I want to setup an Android app which has some records in its db and user can forward a record to server database and display them in a web page

can any one suggest me requirements for this process

Comment: using web service you can do this. make web service in php/.net and pass the required parameter from android to server. At server side make one web page that shown information that you have sent. pass this web page link to as response. Now use this response link at android side to display your contain as web page.

Comment: can u suggest me software requirements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
 private static final String HostUrl =" http://test.gloriatech.in:5657/Service.svc";//(your url)
 private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
 private HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(HostUrl);
SoapPrimitive response=null;
final String methodname="InsertGPSInformation";
    request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,methodname);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    String getImeNumber=telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
    SimpleDateFormat sdfDateTime = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    String newtime =  sdfDateTime.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    request.addProperty("IMEINumber",getImeNumber);
    request.addProperty("Longitude",longitudeField.getText().toString()); 
    request.addProperty("Latitude",latituteField.getText().toString()); 
    request.addProperty("Date",newtime);
    request.addProperty("formName",className);
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
     String result = null;
    try
     {          
        httpTransport.call(NAMESPACE+"IService/"+methodname, envelope);
        response = ( SoapPrimitive )envelope.getResponse();
        result=response.toString();
     }
    catch(Exception e)
     {
         Toast.makeText(this, "Exception"+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.e("Upload Picture Error:",e.getMessage());
     }
    Toast.makeText(this, ""+result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: can u suggest me software requirements

Comment: ksoap2-android-assembly-2.5.4-jar-with-dependencies
And service is .Net Webservice

Answer (score 0):

you can do this in two ways, One is using URL Connection & another one is by accessing the webservies available for that uploading page.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a webservice  or servlet

if you are using webservice then you will have to do something like

```
SoapObject requestObject = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        requestObject.addProperty("name", value);
        requestObject.addProperty("name", value);
        envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(requestObject);
        transportSE = new HttpTransportSE(URL1);
        transportSE.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

        Object obj = (Object) envelope.getResponse();
```

and for servlet

```
HttpResponse response = null;
            HttpEntity httpEntity;
            InputStream responseInput;
            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("*URL here*");

            try {
                entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParams);

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
//              entity.setContentEncoding(HTTP.UTF_8);
//               entity.setContentType("text/html");
            httppost.setEntity(entity);
            try {
                response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                Log.v("Resonse", "Request Send successfully!!!");
                httpEntity = response.getEntity();
                Log.v("Resonse", "Response recieved successfully!!!");
                responseInput = httpEntity.getContent();
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(responseInput));
```

//....and so on